# Unable to play Video in Android LsitView

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have a listView in which

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) { 


                player.cueVideo("KJ9KzGQq0w");
            }
        });


private     YouTubePlayer player= new YouTubePlayer() {

        @Override
        public void setShowFullscreenButton(boolean arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setPlaylistEventListener(PlaylistEventListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setPlayerStateChangeListener(PlayerStateChangeListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setPlaybackEventListener(PlaybackEventListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setOnFullscreenListener(OnFullscreenListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setManageAudioFocus(boolean arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setFullscreenControlFlags(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setFullscreen(boolean arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void seekToMillis(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void seekRelativeMillis(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void release() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void previous() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void play() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void loadVideos(List<String> arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void loadVideos(List<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void loadVideo(String arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void loadVideo(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void loadPlaylist(String arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void loadPlaylist(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPlaying() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getFullscreenControlFlags() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getDurationMillis() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeMillis() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void cueVideos(List<String> arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void cueVideos(List<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void cueVideo(String arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void cueVideo(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void cuePlaylist(String arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void cuePlaylist(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void addFullscreenControlFlag(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

I am using `YouTubeAPI` for doing this

sample code in API

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            //player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
        }
    }
```

I want to play a video as soon as an element in listView is clicked.

Comment: ..but ? what happens ? 
Does it show error or does it show thumbnail at least ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made few changes

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player1,boolean wasRestored) {
        player=player1;
    }



 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) { 
    video_URL="eF9AC2Ce2ow";

    video_player.loadVideo(video_URL);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");` to `player.loadVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");`.
loadVideo will automatically play when it has finished loading.